# Error while creating neutron client

Tags: python, authentication, openstack

I am a newbie with openstack environment and i am trying my hands on with Openstack API. 
I am getting following error while executing a basic script to list networks using neutron API.

Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from neutronclient.v2_0 import client as neutronClient
import os

neutronConnection = neutronClient.Client(
    username=os.environ['OS_USERNAME'],
    password=os.environ['OS_PASSWORD'],
    tenant_name=os.environ['OS_TENANT_NAME'],
    auth_url=os.environ['OS_AUTH_URL']
    )
print neutronConnection
neutronConnection.format = 'json'
neutronConnection.list_networks()
```

Error

```
    neutronConnection.list_networks()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 98, in with_params
    ret = self.function(instance, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 339, in list_networks
    **_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 1334, in list
    for r in self._pagination(collection, path, **params):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 1347, in _pagination
    res = self.get(path, params=params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 1320, in get
    headers=headers, params=params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 1297, in retry_request
    headers=headers, params=params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 1232, in do_request
    self.httpclient.authenticate_and_fetch_endpoint_url()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 152, in authenticate_and_fetch_endpoint_url
    self.authenticate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 249, in authenticate
    self._authenticate_keystone()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 228, in _authenticate_keystone
    allow_redirects=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 138, in _cs_request
    raise exceptions.Unauthorized(message=body)
neutronclient.common.exceptions.Unauthorized: {"error": {"message": "Could not find project, ESS.", "code": 401, "title": "Unauthorized"}}
```

Comment: If i do execute neutron net-list from command line .. it works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that there is a problem with the name of the tenant that you passed in the OS_TENANT_NAME environment variable. Its value is 'ESS', and either there is no tenant with that name, or the user does not have access to it.

If you are able to run the neutron CLI, print out the environment variables you used there and copy them into your code.